# Fields for different languages on the same interface

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I have a node that has many fields but need only the title and body field translated.

This node type has a workflow associated to it and any authenticated user can create that node.

The client requires that fields for language EN/FR are all available on the form

I'm wondering what is the best approach to adopt:
content translation + different fields for each language
or 
Entity field translation

I've tried entity field translation but it does not provide the fields for each language on the same interface and it does not seem to work well with workbench moderation.

Comment: do you have some advance?

Comment: I've added distinct fields for the different languages.
Overwritten the node title through hook_node_view
and used a custom views handler for the title for my views

Comment: if you want you can post your solutions as a answer

Answer (score 3):

You must repeat the fields, because the [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) and the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) (i18n) module don't provive the fields for each language in the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a module for Drupal 7 called [**Dual-language editor** (DLE)](https://www.uottawa.ca/uoweb/en/user-guide/exploring-dual-language-editor) that does this.

For Drupal 8 and 9 there are 2 contrib modules:

[Multilanguage Form Display](https://www.drupal.org/project/mfd): This tries to achieve the same thing by adding a form to translate all fields for each language. Seems that the module may not be stable enough, though.

[Entity Translation Unified Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation_unified_form): I haven't used it yet, but this looks a bit more polished, has more usage and claims support for Paragraphs.